# Allowing CORS to provide error message?

Tags: security, error-handling, xmlhttprequest, cors

Lets say you have an API that is primarily consumed by browsers from other origins.
Each customer has their own subdomain on the API, so .api.service.com

The service allows the customer to define which origins should be allowed to perform CORS-requests.
When a browser with an allowed origin performs a request, the server responds with the expected Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set to the same value as the Origin request header.

When a browser performs a request from an origin that is NOT allowed, the common way to handle this is to respond to the request with a 403 without specifying the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, which will cause the browser to trigger an error on the request. The browser does not, however, expose any information that the error was caused by missing CORS-headers (although it logs a helpful error in the console, usually).

This makes it hard to programatically show a helpful "This origin is not allowed, please configure."-message, since there doesn't seem to be a good way to reliably decide whether the error was caused by a wifi glitch, a network error or an invalid/missing CORS-configuration.

My question is; when the server detects an origin that should not be allowed, instead of responding with no CORS-headers, could it respond with a 403 and include CORS-headers to allow the browser to read the error?

Since every request goes through this process on the API, I'm thinking this should be safe, but I might be overlooking something. Thoughts?